# Need Help : How do I resolve this function?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

```
const getDbInfo = (anArrayOfIDs) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        let arrayOfDbInfoToSendBack = [];
        for(let i = 0; i <= anArrayOfIDs.length-1; i++){
            pool.query(
                "SELECT * FROM `tbl_ofInfo` WHERE tbl_ofInfo.sqlID = '" +
                anArrayOfIDs[i] +
            "';",
            async(err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("error: ", err);
                  } else {
                      for(let k = 0; k <= res.length-1; k++){
                         arrayOfDbInfoToSendBack.push(res);
                          
                      }
                      resolve(arrayOfDbInfoToSendBack);
                      
                  }
            }
            );
            
        }
    });
}
```

Expected this function to return an array of objects with information. I suspect I am using resolve incorrectly and it sending back an array of only 1 object when I want an array of multiple objects in it.

Comment: Why `"SELECT * FROM `tbl_ofInfo` WHERE tbl_ofInfo.sqlID = '" + anArrayOfIDs[i] + "';"` instead of `"SELECT * FROM `tbl_ofInfo` WHERE tbl_ofInfo.sqlID in ('" + anArrayOfIDs.join(", ") + ")';"` ? Also might be a bit more high priority but that's probably vulnerable to [an SQL injection](http://bobbytables.com/) - probably better still to use prepared statements.

Comment: I simplified it for readability purposes. issue i have is its resolving too soon. I want to build the array completely before hitting the resolve.

Comment: be aware of SQL injection :)

Comment: Make the function inside your Promis an async function

Comment: The await for pool result and just like the answer below add resolve to outside of it's scope

Comment: If the one object that is being returned is correct one then problem can be rooted back to the fact that you are resolving inside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL every query is a promise, so there is no need to query inside a promise. To simplify the resolve, you can use async/await.

```
//Setting function asynchronous
const getDbInfo = async (anArrayOfIDs) => { 
    let arrayOfDbInfoToSendBack = [];
    for(let i = 0; i <= anArrayOfIDs.length-1; i++){
       let query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_ofInfo` WHERE tbl_ofInfo.sqlID = '" + anArrayOfIDs[i] + "';"

       //Awaiting until the sql query resolved or rejected
       await pool.query(query,(err, res)=>{
           if (err) console.error(err)
           else {
               for(let k = 0; k <= res.length-1; k++){
                   arrayOfDbInfoToSendBack.push(res);
           }
       })
    }
}
```

Btw, I'm not sure this function will work if you declare it outside your route. Because Nodejs will try to execute it once the server is up and fails for the reason it cannot find an argument of `anArrayOfIDs`. So, use the function inside your route. If you have to use it often, move your function to a different `.js` file, export it from there and then import it as middleware to where you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this piece of code work?

```js
const getDbInfo = (anArrayOfIDs) => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_ofInfo` WHERE tbl_ofInfo.sqlID IN (?)", anArrayOfIDs ,
      (err, res) => {
          if (err) {
          console.log("error: ", err);
          reject(err);
          return;
        } 

        resolve(res)        
      }
    );       
  });
}
```

Comment: No,
its just resolving.. its not sending back an array that is suppose to be built before resolving.

Comment: Does it need to be in a Promise @FCP ? And what do you mean by it's not resolving? Are you handling the promise well? Like `getDbInfo([1,2,3]).then(res => console.log(res));` or `const result = await getDbInfo([1,2,3]);`

Answer (score 0):

If the one object that is being returned is correct one, then problem can be rooted back to the fact that you are resolving inside the for loop.
That means that only first iteration is called and then as promise has already resolved then next iterations are obsolete considering the callback nature of `pool.query` i would assume that putting await before it can solve the problem

```
const getDbInfo = (anArrayOfIDs) => {
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
        let arrayOfDbInfoToSendBack = [];
        anArrayOfIDs.forEach(async (id) => {
            await pool.query(
                "SELECT * FROM `tbl_ofInfo` WHERE tbl_ofInfo.sqlID = '" +
                id +
                "';",
                async (err, res) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("error: ", err);
                    } else {
                        for (let k = 0; k <= res.length - 1; k++) {
                            arrayOfDbInfoToSendBack.push(res);

                        }


                    }
                }
            );
            resolve(arrayOfDbInfoToSendBack);
        });
    });
}
```